# CSV qty (quantity) import issue

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv

I'm having a problem with the gty (and just with the guantity) when importing the products from csv. I'm doing the import from system -> import/export -> import -> Replace Existing Complex Data.

I must say that all the custom attributes and other values are imported with 100% success, but the gty field just want accept the number, either in the format for example "10" or "10.0000". It is always a zero, which is not correct.

I have tried all the possible solutions i could think off, but couldn't figure this out.

What i'm doing wrong! thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that your column title is `qty` - not `gty`. Quantity. Not Guantity.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaa..... thanks benmarks. that was it.

Comment: Nice guestion though